# How to find maxima in python?

Tags: python, optimization

I need to find the maxima of this function in python with the `optimize.fmin` function on the interval [0,7]. How can I do this?

```
def f(x):
    y = np.cos(x) + 2
    return y
```

[task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVnxE.png)

Comment: Can you add your python code snippet as part of the post itself?

Comment: does the code in your snippet not work? Does the tutorial you are following link you to docs that you didn't read?